# How can I change .Designer.cs in C# project?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, dataset, tableadapter

> this._commandCollection[4].Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ILBO_ST41", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "ILBO_ST41", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));

It was part of my .Designer.cs file and It about Insert query.

I want change System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10 to 50.

Is the default value of NVarChar was 10?

Can I change the value in Form.cs file?  How Can I do Without changing direct file?

Comment: I would expect you to be able to fix this *in the designer*. Find where that SQL parameter is defined in the designer, and adjust the properties

Comment: While you _can_ edit .Designer.cs, you shouldn't. You should be able to find this in the Property-Toolbox. Maybe you need to expand an entry.

Comment: I can't find SqlDbType in property of .xsd file. How can I found?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it! I make another tableAdapter in .xsd file. It was applied SqlDbType.NvarChar 50! And I remove original tableAdapter.!

Answer (score 0):

You open the dataset, click on the relevant query in the table adapter, click on the `[...]` button in the Parameters line in the property grid, click in the relevant parameter, and adjust its DbType setting